# Map network drive to VM Virtualbox with CentOS

Tags: windows, virtualbox, centos, putty

I can connect with Putty to my CentOS using the virtual machine's IP address, but I can not map a network drive to the virtual machine from Windows 7 using `\\IP\shared_file`. I use the VM's IP address, and it is right because I can ping to it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is samba started on the VM? What does `su -c '/sbin/service smb status'` say?

Comment: I have the same problem as OP and for me smb `is running...`

Comment: Same for nmb, I've narrowed the problem down to it being a service, but which one I have no idea. Yesterday it worked fine (after hours of trying to get it working) I think there's a chance each time it restarts that the services are started correctly...